# How to bulk delete multiple AWS snapshots using AWS CLI?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

So the command for deleting a AWS Snapshot using SnapshotID is as below

```
aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id snap-1234567890abcdef0
```

I have a list of 400 snapshot IDs that needs deletion. What command should I use to bulk delete them using SnapshotID.

**PS: None of the snapshots are tagged.

Comment: you cannot as there is no command to do that as of now.

Comment: retrieve the list of snapshots and pipe it into something and check if you can iterate over the file. Or copy the snapshots into an editor, enter column selection mode and insert the aws command in front, or replace every link break with the aws command, etc. There are a million answers to achieve, you simply have to find the one you are most familiar with.

Comment: something like this may work: `ec2-describe-snapshots | grep SNAPSHOT | sort -k 5 | head -200 | awk '{print "Deleting-> " $2; system("ec2-delete-snapshot " $2)}'`

Comment: CLI and default output format may have changed? My experience:
* Had to use `aws ec2 describe-snapshots` as the first command.
* Had to add `--snapshot-id` option to the delete command.
* Had to set text output using `aws config` command, or `--output` option.
* Still had some issues with sorting column & printing column. 
* Instead of fighting field separators and column counts, might be easier to use JSON or YAML output, and iterate with Python.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's a solution that might sound silly, but is highly effective...

I typically create an **Excel spreadsheet with a list of IDs** in the first column.

I then create a second column with a formula that contains the full command, with a reference to the first column that inserts the ID at the appropriate place. I then **Copy Down** the formula for all lines.

To test the formula, I copy the first line and **paste it into my shell** to confirm that it works as expected.

I then paste all the lines generated by the formula into a text file and then **execute the text file in the shell**. It will run faster if you do it from an Amazon EC2 instance since it decreases network latency, but running it from your own computer will work just as well. Simply go grab a cup of coffee.

If the thought of using Excel abhors you, then you could write a simple script in Python that iterates through the list and calls the [`delete_snapshot()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.delete_snapshot) command.

Comment: This exactly I followed using a bash script. Had to tweak a little because some of the snapshots are in different region. But this solution worked like a charm.

Comment: @John Rotenstein may you share the excel formula for this?

Comment: @Maciej If the ID is in the first column, it would simply be `="aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id "&a1`

Answer (score 8):

# Delete all snapshots withing us-west-2 region:

```
for K in $(aws ec2 --region us-west-2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids=${AWS_OWNER_ID} --query 'Snapshots[*].SnapshotId' --output=text); do
aws ec2 --region us-west-2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $K
done
```

Comment: You can simply do `--owner-ids self` to list snapshots owned by the current AWS account.

Answer (score 0):

### Batch delete snapshots for aws-cli 2.2

Tested on the following version / system:

```
% aws --version
aws-cli/2.2.26 Python/3.8.8 Darwin/20.6.0 exe/x86_64 prompt/off
```

> Wait... it's truncating snapshot IDs, so the delete fails.  (?!)

> Heck. I'll revisit this in a bit. :-(

The command:

```sh
% aws ec2 describe-snapshots | grep SNAPSHOT | sort -k 6 | head -20 \
    | awk '{print "Deleting-> " $4,$6,$8,$9,$10; \
      system("aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id " $8)}'
```

The output:

```sh
Deleting-> image.vmdk 099720109477 snap-005349429a002f03b 2019-05-08T11:09:45.481000+00:00 completed
Deleting-> image.vmdk 099720109477 snap-00ea72d226a56a8cf 2019-05-29T16:27:54.246000+00:00 completed
    :
```

Notes:

- Command is in the v2 format, matches that given in question.
- Grep: for SNAPSHOT to skip any TAGS lines.
- Sort: for me it was **field 6**.
- Head: 20 for testing; increase once it works.
- Awk print: shows several fields ($4,$6,$8...) for tracking.
- Awk system: using **$8**, based on previous

Fields changed from those given by an earlier commenter.

- Could be aws cli differences, *or*
- Could be OS/shell differences.
- Either way, do a short test printing the fields first.

Thanks for ideas in [this AWS forum thread](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?messageID=109517).

Answer (score 0):

**Note : this will delte all snapshot from your region that configured in AWS CLI**
use this command to save all snapshot id in sgn.txt file.

**Command:**

aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids self  --query 'Snapshots[].SnapshotId' > sgn.txt

---

```
[
    "snap-04030b95f2ebcbe6e",
    "snap-06e1a8394774c8486",
    "snap-03c6659d966953d6c",
    "snap-02de629dc082b33cb",
    "snap-033dfc52483c09455"
]
```

**remove brackets and make file looks like this and add ',' to last id**

```
"snap-04030b95f2ebcbe6e",
"snap-06e1a8394774c8486",
"snap-03c6659d966953d6c",
"snap-02de629dc082b33cb",
"snap-033dfc52483c09455",
```

now use below python code to delete all snapshot

**code:**

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2',region_name='us-east-1')
file=open('sgn.txt','r')
l=file.readlines()
for i in l: 
    s=i.strip()
    s=s[1:len(s)-2]
    client.delete_snapshot(SnapshotId=s)
    print(s,"deleted")
```

**Note:-**
you must have configure the aws cli to run this python file and you also need to install boto3 module in python

Answer (score 0):

Using @Lock-o-motiffe 's answer

If you are trying to search by description or filter by any other thing like tags, and also have aws sso, first do

```
aws ec2 describe-snapshots --region us-west-2 --owner-ids self --profile <your-profile> --filters '{"Name":"description","Values":["Created by CreateImage(*) for *"]}' --query 'Snapshots[*].SnapshotId' --output=text --max-items 5
```

Then do the following and remove the --max-items flag:

```
for K in $(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --region us-west-2 --owner-ids self --profile <your-profile> --filters '{"Name":"description","Values":["Created by CreateImage(*) for *"]}' --query 'Snapshots[*].SnapshotId' --output=text); do
aws ec2 delete-snapshot --region us-west-2 --profile <your-profile> --snapshot-id $K
done
```

The Name can be any of the ones listed in filter options here https://awscli.amazonaws.com/v2/documentation/api/latest/reference/ec2/describe-images.html such as architecture, name, tag, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the answer from @Lock-o-motiffe above.

It almost worked for me, but the `describe-snapshots` command outputs its format in one line, separated with tabs, which caused the loop to fail. Tweaked it (in a Mac environment) by adding a `sed` that converts tabs to line breaks:

```
for K in $(aws ec2 --region REGION_HERE describe-snapshots --owner-ids=OWNER_ID_HERE --query 'Snapshots[*].SnapshotId' --output=text | sed 's/\t/\n/g' | head -2); do
echo $K
  aws ec2 --region REGION_HERE delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $K
done
```

Answer (score 0):

Due to a backup process with no lifecycle policy, we discovered tens of thousands of snapshots, linked to AMIs.  The answers here will probably fail if you have thousands of snapshots, because "argument list too long".  And if the snapshots are linked to AMIs, you have to deregister the AMIs first.  It took many hours to run, so I output the date.

Here's the script I used, to deregister >10k AMIs then delete >100k snapshots.
WARNING: this will delete ALL your backups.  Before running this, protect the AMIs/snapshots you want to keep.

```
date
# deregister AMIs in batches of 100 
numAMIs=$(aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --output text|wc -w)
echo "Deregistering $numAMIs AMIs"
for i in $( seq 1 $((numAMIs/100)) ); do 
  echo $i
  for image in $( aws ec2 describe-images --owners self --query "Images[0:100].ImageId" --output text ); do
    aws ec2 deregister-image --image-id $image
  done  
done

date

# delete snapshots in batches of 100
numSnapshots=$(aws ec2 describe-snapshots --owner-ids self --output text|wc -w)
echo "Deleting $numSnapshots snapshots"
for i in $(seq 1 $((numSnapshots/100)) ); do 
  echo $i
  for snapshot in $( aws ec2 describe-snapshots  --owner-ids self --query "Snapshots[0:100].SnapshotId" --output text ); do 
    aws ec2 delete-snapshot --snapshot-id $snapshot
  done
done 
date
```